# .desktop {display:none;} / .mobile {display:inline;}

Tags: html, css

I'm currently enrolled in a class for HTML/CSS and the book recommends me to use 
.desktop {display:none;} / .mobile {display:inline;} along with 
div class="desktop" { } / div class="mobile" { }

The book says that the mobile class/style will only appear on mobile and the desktop class/style will only appear on desktop, but the mobile class/style always appears and the desktop class/style doesn't appear at all. Is there something else I can use that does this function? I'm using Notepad++ for both HTML and CSS and my objective is to make my website responsive.

Comment: Please make your question more clear i don't understand you provide for us a code or anything can help us to help you.

Comment: My book says to use  .desktop {display:none;} on the my styles sheet and div class="desktop" { } on my HTML page to make the items within the desktop div to only show up when loaded on a desktop device, but when I do it, it makes the items within the desktop div disappear entirely. I'm trying to see if there is something else besides "none" that I can set the display to.

Comment: Yes `display:none;` remove the view from your page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to want to use media queries to make your website responsive. Here's an example of the CSS you'll want to use:

```
// Anything up here will be your global/mobile styles
.desktop {
  display: none;
}

// Activates when your screen width is above 768px
// anything in here will be your desktop styles
@media(min-width: 768px) {
  .desktop {
    display: inline;
  }

  .mobile {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

And for your HTML you'll want just two elements, one for desktop, and one for mobile.

```
<div class="desktop">
  Desktop Version
</div>

<div class="mobile">
  Mobile Version
</div>
```

Comment: TY exactly what i was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

**First** You can use [ATOM](https://atom.io/) or [SublimeText](https://www.sublimetext.com/) or [VS CODE](https://code.visualstudio.com/) as editor to your codes that will help you alote.

**Second** if you use in your .desktop style `display:none;` then the of curse the

view will be gone ! so if you want to use two view to each device your code must

be like this :

```
.desktop {
     display:inline;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .mobile {
        display:inline;
    }
    .desktop {
        display:none !important;
    }
}
```